# How to recover locked ATTiny 85

Tags: avr, crystal, attiny85

I was following this tutorial: http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695 and by mistake I uploaded code with 8 MHz External clock settings. 
The tutorial says 

`Warning: make sure you select “internal” not “external” or your microcontroller will stop working (until you connect an external clock to it)`

Is it possible to unlock it without external crystal clock? If not, what crystal do I need to unlock it?

Thank you :)

Comment: you probably need to reset the fuses (https://sites.google.com/site/wayneholder/attiny-fuse-reset)

Comment: If you've got an Arduino lying around, you can use that to generate a square wave that you can then feed in to the CLKI (PB3) pin.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I have Uno that I used to program ATTiny. Is there any sample code how to do this?

Comment: Adding `pinMode(3,OUTPUT);TIMSK2=0;OCR2A=0;TCCR2A=(1<<COM2B0)+(1<<WGM21);TCCR2B=(1<<CS20);` to the setup() function of the ArduinoISP sketch should get digital pin 3 toggling at 8MHz.

Comment: Your chip is not "locked" it merely requires a clock source perhaps not present in your programmer.  Not mis-stating the issue is key to correctly solving the difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices. Either use a high-voltage programmer to correct the fuses, or feed a clock signal into the CLKI (PB3) pin of the ATTiny.

In order to use ISP, the processor must have a clock signal. This can either be the internal oscillator, or an external oscillator. Once the processor is set to external clock, ISP will no longer work if there is no external clock signal.

The HV programmer can get around this by using a different programming mode to change the fuses and set them back to internal oscillator, allowing ISP to be re-enabled.

Alternatively, as you are using an Arduino as an ISP device, it is fairly easy to have the Arduino produce a clock signal that you can then feed into the ATTiny (even if the fuses are set to external oscillator as opposed to external clock, this will still work). You can add the following lines to the `setup()` function of the ArduinoISP sketch:

```
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
TIMSK2=0;
OCR2A=0;
TCCR2A=(1<<COM2B0)+(1<<WGM21);
TCCR2B=(1<<CS20);
```

That will make use of Timer 2, and the OC2B pin (digital pin 3) to generate an 8MHz clock signal without affecting the operation of the ArduinoISP sketch.

---

<sup>It's been a while since I've tried this and wrote the above code based on looking at the datasheet registers, so there may be bugs/mistakes in it.</sup>